# Replace commas in escaped double quote csv tring in Azure Logic App

Tags: javascript, azure, csv, azure-logic-apps

I am using an Azure Logic app to import .csv files and convert the content to JSON.  Here is a sample of the data:

`[
"ID,SupplierName,StreetName,CityName,Region,PostalCode,EmailAddress,ABN,ContactPersonName",
"111111,ACME Pty Ltd,"27/35 william street, Merton",Jamieson,VIC,3131,test@test.com,11111111111,John Doe",
"222222,"Signage, Steves","Level 2, 21 Jump Sreet",Melbourne,VIC,3000,foo@test.com,22222222222,Craig David",
]`

I don't have control of the .csv format as it is coming from a vendor.

I am using the following flow to split the .csv and format it as json.

The issue is lines that contain quoted strings with commas inside.  The split statement breaks out the data too much for data like "27/35 william street, Merton".
I was thinking of replacing the commas in the escaped strings using regular expressions (perhaps before the string split) using a javascript action.

I'm not great with creating regular expressions.  Can someone help me write one to detect commas within double quotes (that may or may not be quoted) as per the above .csv structure please?

[image]

Comment: And if you have quotes in the data? Do yourself a favour and use a proper tool for such a thing, this will never work 100% of the time. The Advanced Data Operations connector has a CSV to JSON option along with others that are extremely useful. I’d look into something like that.

Answer (score 1):

> Replace commas in escaped double quote csv tring in Azure Logic App.
> I was thinking of replacing the commas in the escaped strings using regular expressions (perhaps before the string split) using a javascript action.

To replace commas with space You can use below **`design`**:

[image]

**`Java script code:`**

```
var rithdata = workflowContext.actions.Compose.outputs;
var result = rithdata.replace(/("(?:[^"]|"")*")|,/g, function (match, p1) {
    return p1 ? p1.replace(/,/g, '|') : match;
});
var c= result.replace(/,/g, ' ');
return c.replace(/\|/g, ',');
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Commas have replace with space inside double quoted values.